# xml file parsing in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

xml file :

```
<global>
    <rtmp>
        <fcsapp>
            <password>
                <key>hello123</key>
                <key>check123</key>
            </password>
        </fcsapp>
    </rtmp>
</global>
```

python code : To obtain all the key tag values.
hello123 
check123

```
using xml.etree.ElementTree

for streams in xmlRoot.iter('global'):
    xpath = "/rtmp/fcsapp/password"
    tag = "key"
    for child in streams.findall(xpath):
        resultlist.append(child.find(tag).text)

    print resultlist
```

The output obtained is `[hello123]`, but I want it to display both (`[hello123, check123]`)

How do I obtain this?

Comment: Use code formatting (the `{}` button), not quoting... (Then you don't have to mangle your XML).

Answer (score 2):

Using [lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) and [cssselect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect) I would do it like this:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> doc = fromstring(open("foo.xml", "r").read())
>>> doc.cssselect("password key")
[<Element key at 0x7f77a6786cb0>, <Element key at 0x7f77a6786d70>]
>>> [e.text for e in  doc.cssselect("password key")]
['hello123 \n                      ', 'check123 \n                  ']
```

Answer (score 2):

With [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) You can do it in the following way:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<global>
    <rtmp>
        <fcsapp>
            <password>
                <key>hello123</key>
                <key>check123</key>
            </password>
        </fcsapp>
    </rtmp>
</global>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
result = tree.xpath('//password/key/text()')
print result #  ['hello123', 'check123']
```

Comment: Nice use of tagging there :)

Answer (score 0):

try beautifulsoup package "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup"

Answer (score 0):

using xml.etree.ElementTree

```
for streams in xmlRoot.iter('global'):
    xpath = "/rtmp/fcsapp/password"
    tag = "key"
    for child in streams.iter(tag):
        resultlist.append(child.text)

    print resultlist
```

have to iter over the "key" tag in for loop to obtain the desired result. The above code solves the problem.